# grep 5 seconds of input from the serial port inside a shell-script

Tags: bash, shell, serial-port

I've got a device that I'm operating next to my PC and as it runs it's spitting log lines out it's serial port. I have this wired to my PC and I can see the log lines fine if I'm using either minicom or something like:

```
ttylog -b 115200 -d /dev/ttyS0
```

I want to write 5 seconds of the device serial output to a temp file (or assign it to a variable) and then later grep that file for keywords that will let me know how the device is operating. I've already tried redirecting the output to a file while running the command in the background, and then sleeping 5 seconds and killing the process, but the log lines never get written to my temp file. Example:

```
touch tempFile
ttylog -b 115200 -d /dev/ttyS0 >> tempFile &
serialPID=$!
sleep 5
#kill ${serialPID} #does not work, gets wrong PID
killall ttylog
cat tempFile
```

The file gets created but never filled with any data. I can also replace the ttylog line with:

```
ttylog -b 115200 -d /dev/ttyS0 |tee -a tempFile &
```

In neither case do I ever see any log lines logged to stdout or the log file unless I have multiple versions of ttylog running by mistake (see commented out line, D'oh).

I have no idea what's going on here. It seems to be a failure of redirection within my script.

Am I on the right track? Is there a better way to sample 5 seconds of the serial port?

Comment: Why not add a timestamp to every Nth line and record 104 seconds of data, and then split it into 20-21 chunks using some utility?

Comment: If you add `jobs -l; echo $serialPID` after `serialPID=$!` do the PIDs match?

Comment: @lpthnc  I've got 1 to 200 commands to issue and any one of those commands might add more commands to the push-pop stack, so I only want to deal with one command at a time.

The script also operates The Box and automatically issues the commands that are under test. I really want to keep it in the "start recording - issue command - stop recording - grep for results - update stats" algorithm

Comment: @Dennis Williamson 


I did something similar, but let me try your suggestion. 



      root-# ./ser_test.sh  #(yes I have to run as root)



[1]+ 27576 Running ttylog -b 115200 -d /dev/ttyS0 27577 | tee -a tempFile &



the PID is:  27577





I'm getting the PID of `tee` , but I get the correct PID when I change it to `>>`. This is good because at some point I may need to run the script multiple times to test multiple boxes on different serial ports and `killall` is a blunt tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like maybe ttylog is buffering its output.  Have you tried running it with -f or --flush?

Comment: -f is not a valid flag for ttylog, or perhaps I don't understand your question?

Comment: D'oh. `strings /usr/sbin/ttylog` show the -f option as available, but it's not in the man page. I'll give it a try.

Comment: That seemed to do the trick, at least in my sample code where I cat to stdout instead of grep things. Thanks, now I can integrate this in with the uber-script.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the [unbuffer](http://expect.nist.gov/#examples) script that comes with [expect](http://expect.nist.gov).

Comment: will check this out shortly. It looks promising. I did, however find an easier solution in the -f option suggested by David Norman.

Answer (score 0):

`ttylog` has a `--timeout` option, where you can simply specify for how many seconds it should run.

So, in your case, you could do

```
ttylog --baud 115200 --device /dev/ttyS0 --timeout 5
```

and it would just run for 5 seconds and then stop.
Indeed it also has the `-f` option as mentioned which flushes, but if you'd use `--timeout` you would not be needing that.